# Anyone know a tool for doing a keyword search against all script included in a page?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Within Firebug, I can look at script includes and search each include individually.  I would like to be able to search all includes at once.  Does anyone know a tool that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) on your source tree :)

Comment: That's going to include files not included from teh particular page, it will also miss javascript included from other servers, as well as generated script blocks.  There's definitely value in such a search though I do such searches at time, but I guess I'm looking for a 3rd search option.

Comment: Maybe I should learn ack though.  I use findstr, which is pretty dated.